# @classmethod and method without self

Tags: python, self, class-method

Let's suppose we have this class:

```
class Demo:

    def __init__(self, str):
        self.str = str

    def fromBytes1(bytes):
        return Demo(bytes2str(bytes))

    @classmethod
    def fromBytes2(cls, bytes):
        return cls(bytes2str(bytes))
```

What is the difference between `fromBytes1` and `fromBytes2`, except for the fact that you can't call the 1st method in the following way?

```
Demo().fromBytes1(bytes)
```

Is there something more subtle that I cannot see here?

Comment: You're missing a `self` parameter in the first case. Also, could you give the methods slightly different names?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I thought that omission was intentional. It lets you use the method as a pseudo-static method (`Demo.fromBytes(…)` works), but `Demo().fromBytes()` does something unexpected.

Comment: I think you can define methods without ```self```.

Comment: @igol you *can* but you **shouldn't**.  Don't write something like your version 1 ever. That should just be a regular function, outside of the class. In any case, the difference is obvious, a `classmethod` will implicitly get passed *the class* as it's first positional argument

Comment: If you really want the first variant, make it an ``@staticmethod``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you only intend to call the methods from a class object, all the important differences are in inheritance. Say you have

```
class Test(Demo):
    pass
```

If you do `Test.fromBytes1(b'ar')`, you get an instance of `Demo`.

If you do `Test.fromBytes2(b'ar')`, you get an instance of `Test`.

The second method is more flexible because you *can* hard code `Demo` or `__class__` into it directly, but you *must* hard code it in the first case.

Comment: So, with @classmethod, you don't need to override the method?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yeah I know that. I wrote that you **can't** call the 1st variant with ```Demo().fromBytes(some_bytes)```

Comment: @MisterMiyagi. Of course. I have no idea why I didn't write it that way. Will fix momentarily.

Comment: @igol. I misread. Will fix ASAP

Comment: @igol. F i x  e d